# Can we assign a character value to int and print the same character value without using any conversion in C++

Tags: c++

This question was asked in an interview and i said without using any conversion it can not be done. 
I could not find any satisfactory answer from google ;please help me to solve this.

Comment: You certainly can't assign a `char` value to `int` without a conversion. `int i = 'a';` involves an implicit conversion from `char` (the type of `'a'`) to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
When you store a character in a int variable. It implicitly converts it into number equivalent to its ASCII value.
And similarly you can print it directly using putchar or putch functions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `printf("%c", val);` to print the character value of the integer.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int i = 'a';
    putchar(i);
}
```